# setVisibility para um ImageView de um Grid

Tags: java, android

Tenho um grid com uma imagem em cada item. Em cima de cada imagem tem uma outra imagem menor (icone de visto, para dizer que o item foi selecionado) só que invisível.
Eu estou tentando fazer com que quando a pessoa da um clique longo a imagem menor do item que ele clicou fique visível. Como fazer esta parte da imagem do item ficar invisível ao ser clicada?

Tentei isto mas não da certo

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("CLICK", "LONG CLICK");
                selectedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImageView);
                selectedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Assim apenas a imagem do primeiro item muda. Eu sei que a lógica ta errada, que fazendo assim ele realmente vai mudar só o primeiro item, mas como ainda estou aprendendo Android, não estou conseguindo fazer com que ele fique visível apenas para o item pressionado...

Como fazer para ele pegar a posição exata? (ele está capturando a posição certa, já verifiquei log.d com position, o problema é na hora de pegar a imagem correta, já que não mencionei nenhuma posição, e não sei como fazer isso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você fala que está usando uma `GridView` mas o código refere uma `listView`. Vou partir do pressuposto que é apenas um erro de nome da variável.

A `View` que foi clicada é passada ao `onItemLongClick` na variável ***view*** que aparece na declaração do método.
Use-a, utilizando o método `findViewById` desse objecto: ***view***.findViewById(..);, para ter acesso aos itens contidos nela.

Substitua esta linha do código:

```
selectedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImageView);
```

por esta:

```
selectedImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectedImageView);
```

Espero que isto seja o que você quer.